# How to understand "?." symbol in Entity Framework source code?

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

I'm studying Entity Framework source code and find a lot of `?.` symbols in this project. I can't understand the function of `?.`.

For example, we can find `?.` symbol in `DbContext.cs` like below:

```
public virtual void Dispose()
{
    _disposed = true;
    _serviceScope?.Dispose();
    _setInitializer = null;
    _changeTracker = null;
    _stateManager = null;
    _changeDetector = null;
    _graphAttacher = null;
    _model = null;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The `?.` operator is a new construct in C#6, called the ["null-conditional" operator](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/06/05/c.net-little-wonders-null-conditional-operator-in-c-6.aspx).

By using it, `Dispose()` will only be executed if `_serviceScope` is not `null`. Otherwise, you run the risk of throwing a  `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shortcut for If _serviceScope is not null then _serviceScope.Dispose();

For your reference it was introduced in the new [c# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) as a null-conditional operator

Comment: This isn't strictly correct. It's not a shortcut. It's effectively the **replacement** for the code you mentioned, but not the **equivalent** of. The code you posted is **not thread-safe**, but the null-conditional operator is.